# Espresso AmbiguousViewMatcherException

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

I am getting AmbiguousViewMatcherException exception while trying to write a code on interacting a listview item. Scenario is as follows.

I have a listview with two views

1. textview
2. buttonView

I have almost 250 rows in the list. All buttons have text "Book it" or "Cancelled". They are in a shuffled order. I want to direct Espresso to click on first "Book it" button in the list. I have tried a lot of scenarios and still couldn't get a fix for this. Please someone help me.

Following is my code right now

```
onView(withId(R.id.List))
                .check(matches(withAdaptedData(withItemContent("Book it"))));
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private static Matcher<View> withAdaptedData(final Matcher<Object> dataMatcher) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with class name: ");
                dataMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                if (!(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
                    return false;
                }
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                Adapter adapter = ((AdapterView) view).getAdapter();
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (dataMatcher.matches(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   com.bottegasol.com.migym.EmpireSportFit:id/List' matches multiple
>   views in the hierarchy. Problem views are marked with
>   '****MATCHES****' below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I found, hope it helps:

```
public void testClickOnFirstAndFifthItemOfLength8() {
    onData(is(withItemSize(8)))
      .atPosition(0)
      .perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.selection_row_value))
      .check(matches(withText("10")));
    onData(is(withItemSize(8)))
      .atPosition(4)
      .perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.selection_row_value))
      .check(matches(withText("14")));
  }
```

source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/AdapterViewTest.java

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you're having multiple view whose id equals `R.id.List`. You should first check the view hierarchy and replace the list id (`id/List`) with a unique id for the view you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Put List View in allOff() because your id List is used at Many times in the Project.

onView(allOff(withId(R.id.List)))
                .check(matches(withAdaptedData(withItemContent("Book it"))));